# Remove CURLOPT_HEADER return data

Tags: php, curl

I am do some curl process, some site must set `CURLOPT_HEADER, true`, so that could get the html code.

```
$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$html = curl_exec($ch2);
curl_close($ch2);
echo $html;
```

the return data like:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK  Date: Wed, 14 Nov 2012 17:58:26 GMT  Expires: Wed, 14 Nov 2012 18:08:26 GMT  Cache-Control: max-age=600... 
<html...
```

So how to remove some data before `<html>`(The CURLOPT_HEADER return data: HTTP/1.0 200 OK...)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`CURLOPT_HEADER` does not affect what the site returns to you. You can remove it and if you get empty content back - then something else is wrong.

`CURLOPT_HEADER` is just for your convenience so you can see what the server said back to your script. Some web API's pass data in the headers and this allows you to access it.

You can split the content from the header like this

```
list($header, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $content, 2); // Notice the "2" limit!
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution in the accepted answer is nice and easy, but it won't work as expected if the response is redirected.

Here is another solution that works with redirects, but requires some more lines:

```
$header_size=curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header=trim(substr($content,0,$header_size)); //Get the header and trim it to remove \r\n
$body=substr($content,$header_size); //Get the body
```